# Multipe Queries and ResultSets stored in one ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, resultset

I'm trying to store multiple ResultSets into one ArrayList. I'm catching an error on my while-loop at the first ResultSet.

Here's my code:

```
List<String> target= new ArrayList<String>();

try{
    wpCall.Connect("database");
            wpCall.ResetParms();
                sql = "SELECT column";
                sql += "FROM table";
                sql += "WHERE col2= 'val1'";
                sql += "AND col3= 'field2'";
            ResultSet rst1 = wpCall.GetResult(sql);
                while(rst1.next()) {
                    String values= rst1.getString(1);
                    target.add(values);
                }
    wpCall.Connect("database");
            wpCall.ResetParms();
                sql = "SELECT column";
                sql += "FROM table";
                sql += "WHERE col2= 'val2'";
                sql += "AND col3= 'field2'";
            ResultSet rst1 = wpCall.GetResult(sql);
                while(rst1.next()) {
                    String values2= rst1.getString(1);
                    target.add(values2);
                }
  } 
  finally { 
     System.out.print("Values: " + Target+ "\n");
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What error? Please provide stacktrace

Comment: why you start variable an method names with capitals? Hard to read and understand.

Comment: I suggest you print your `sql` before trying to call it. It may give you a clue as to why you get errors.

Comment: And I want to use the ArrayList in other areas

Comment: Class name must start with capital but method and variables should be in camel case.

Comment: @Sandeep nothing is shown

Comment: Have you debugged the code to verify values are really added?

Comment: That `try` should have a `catch` clause. And in it, there should be an `e.printStackTrace()` (Assuming you name the exception `e`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL is malformed, you have missed some spaces:

Your first statement should be:

```
sql = "SELECT column";
sql += " FROM table";
sql += " WHERE col2= 'val1'";
sql += " AND col3= 'field2'";
```

And your second statement should be:

```
sql = "SELECT column";
sql += " FROM table";
sql += " WHERE col2= 'val2'";
sql += " AND col3= 'field2'";
```

Comment: @Frank without spaces your first query would be `SELECT columnFROM tableWHERE col2= 'val1'AND col3= 'field2'`

Comment: Thanks, but now my arraylist only have the first resultset value...any idea what to do?